# Pandas group by result to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'audio': ['audio1', 'audio1', 'audio2', 'audio2', 'audio3', 'audio3'],
    'text': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6'],
    'login': ['operator1', 'operator2', 'operator3', 'operator4', 'operator5', 'operator6'] 
})
```

i'm trying to aggregate it like this:

```
x1 = x.groupby('audio')['text'].agg(
    [
    ('text1', lambda x : x.iat[0]),
    ('text2', lambda x : x.iat[1]),
    ('leven', lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.iat[0], x.iat[1])) #some function works with grouped text
    ]
).reset_index()
```

and it works but i also need to add grouped logins to row, to make row like this:

```
audio, text1, text2, leven, login1, login2
```

I tried something like `lambda x : x.ait[0, 1]` but it doesnt work

Comment: Is the data always ordered and in pairs of two rows belonging together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your data frame, I am thinking of pivoting the data frame, below is my approach which makes use of **[`groupby().cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)** and **[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)** with some column formatting to create a pivotted dataframe.

**Option1:**
Then you could make use of **[`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)** to apply the function

```
m = x.assign(k=x.groupby('audio').cumcount().add(1)).set_index(['audio','k']).unstack()
m.columns=[f"{a}{b}" for a,b in m.columns]
m = m.assign(leven=m.apply(lambda x: 
              Levenshtein.distance(x['text1'],x['text2']),1)).reset_index()
```

---

```
    audio  text1  text2     login1     login2  leven
0  audio1  text1  text2  operator1  operator2      1
1  audio2  text3  text4  operator3  operator4      1
2  audio3  text5  text6  operator5  operator6      1
```

**Option2:** (*I would prefer this*)

You can also use a list comprehension to do the same , just replace the last line with:

```
m = x.assign(k=x.groupby('audio').cumcount().add(1)).set_index(['audio','k']).unstack()
m.columns=[f"{a}{b}" for a,b in m.columns]
m = m.assign(leven=[Levenshtein.distance(a,b) for 
               a,b in zip(m['text1'],m['text2'])]).reset_index()
```

---

```
    audio  text1  text2     login1     login2  leven
0  audio1  text1  text2  operator1  operator2      1
1  audio2  text3  text4  operator3  operator4      1
2  audio3  text5  text6  operator5  operator6      1
```

**Option3:**

If location of `leven` column is important, you can use [**`df.insert`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
m=x.assign(k=x.groupby('audio').cumcount().add(1)).set_index(['audio','k']).unstack()
m.columns=[f"{a}{b}" for a,b in m.columns]
m.insert(2,'leven',[Levenshtein.distance(a,b) for a,b in zip(m['text1'],m['text2'])])
m=m.reset_index()
```

---

```
    audio  text1  text2  leven     login1     login2
0  audio1  text1  text2      1  operator1  operator2
1  audio2  text3  text4      1  operator3  operator4
2  audio3  text5  text6      1  operator5  operator6
```

Comment: nice, you might want to look into `FuzzyWuzzy` to use the Levenshtein Distance Algorithm

Comment: @Datanovice yep , however I believe OP uses [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) one here. regardless any func should work :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
x1 = x.groupby('audio',)['login'].agg(
     [
     ('operator1', lambda x : x.iat[0]),
     ('operator2', lambda x : x.iat[1]),
     ('leven', lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.iat[0], x.iat[1])) #some function works with grouped text
     ]
 ).reset_index()

 x2 = x.groupby('audio',)['text'].agg(
     [
     ('text1', lambda x : x.iat[0]),
     ('text2', lambda x : x.iat[1]),
     ('leven', lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.iat[0], x.iat[1])) #some function works with grouped text
     ]
 ).reset_index()

x1.merge(x2)

    audio  operator1  operator2  leven  text1  text2
0  audio1  operator1  operator2      1  text1  text2
1  audio2  operator3  operator4      1  text3  text4
2  audio3  operator5  operator6      1  text5  text6
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great when you have a lot of columns, it automitcally expands them so you don't have to manually list them.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'audio': ['audio1', 'audio1', 'audio2', 'audio2', 'audio3', 'audio3'],
    'text': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6'],
    'login': ['operator1', 'operator2', 'operator3', 'operator4', 'operator5', 'operator6'] 
})


text = x.groupby(['audio']).agg(list)['text'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'text{x+1}')

login = x.groupby(['audio']).agg(list)['login'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'login{x+1}')

text['leven'] = df.apply(lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.text1, x.text2), axis=1) 

df = text.assign(**login)

        text1  text2  leven     login1     login2
audio                                            
audio1  text1  text2      1  operator1  operator2
audio2  text3  text4      1  operator3  operator4
audio3  text5  text6      1  operator5  operator6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your `agg` expression like this:

```
x1 = x.groupby('audio').agg({'text':[
    ('text1', lambda x : x.iat[0]),
    ('text2', lambda x : x.iat[1])
    ('leven', lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.iat[0], x.iat[1])) #some function works with grouped text
    ],
    'login': [
    ('login1', lambda x : x.iat[0]),
    ('login2', lambda x : x.iat[1])]
    }
).droplevel(0,axis=1).reset_index()
```